# After running python script weird signs back

Tags: python, plc

I searched and research about my problem but it is a bit difficult because I don't have really a error (code) to search at.

I try to communicate between my RPI and a PLC, after running the script I get (python Temp_buiten.py) responds is like below, but the output of the script is correct, I get the value into my PLC as a Float like i want but every loop i get this responds in my command line:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/scripts $ python Temp_buiten.py
@▒
A▒
pi@raspberrypi:~/scripts $
```

I am NOT a python programmer so i hope someone can help me out. The script I try to run:

```
#!python3
#---------------Basis-------------------------
import sys
import datetime
import time
import os
import subprocess
import urllib2
import json
import base64
#--------------PLC Snap7----------------------
import S71200
from time import sleep
import snap7
from snap7.util import *
import struct
#---------------Settings----------------------
domoticzserver="192.168.1.210:8080"
domoticzusername = "Secret"
domoticzpassword = "Secret"
device = "558"
log_to_file = False
plc = S71200.S71200("192.168.1.242")
#---------------Variabelen--------------------
temp1 = 0.0
temp_woonkamer = {}
hum = 0.0
hum_stat = 0 #0 t/m 4
sensorids = ["28-0000062723e6"]

#---------------Wachtwoordenzooi--------------
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (domoticzusername,    domoticzpassword)).replace('\n', '')
domoticzurl = 'http://'+ domoticzserver +'/json.htm?  type=devices&rid='+device
#---------------Logging-----------------------
def log(message):
   print message
   if log_to_file == True:
      logfile = open(sys.argv[0] + '.log', "a")
      logfile.write(message + "\n")
      logfile.close()
#---------------Info ophalen------------------
def domoticzrequest (url):
  request = urllib2.Request(url)
  request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
  #print(request)
  response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  return response.read()
#--------------Status-------------------------
json_object = json.loads(domoticzrequest(domoticzurl))

if json_object["status"] == "OK":
    temp1 = json_object["result"][0]['Temp']
    hum = json_object["result"][0]['Humidity']
    plc.writeMem("FREAL204",temp1)
    sleep(1)
else:
    print(device + "NOT OK")


for sensor in range(len(sensorids)):
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/"+ sensorids[sensor] +"/w1_slave")
  # Lees alle dat uit het "bestand" in een variabele.
    text = tfile.read()
  # Sluit het "bestand" nadat we het gelezen hebben.
    tfile.close()
  # We gaan nu de tekst splitsen per nieuwe regel (\n)
  # en we selecteren de 2e regel [1] (1e regel = [0])
    secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
  # Splits de regel in "woorden", er wordt gespleten op de spaties.
  # We selecteren hier het 10 "woord" [9] (tellend vanaf 0)
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
  # De eerste 2 karakters zijn "t=", deze moeten we weghalen.
  # we maken meteen van de string een integer (nummer).
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
  # De temperatuurwaarde moeten we delen door 1000 voor de juiste waarde.
    temp_woonkamer[sensor] = temperature / 1000

    plc.writeMem("FREAL200",temp_woonkamer[sensor])
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Try debugging your script by adding a couple of print statements: `print('1111')` and `print('2222')`. By properly placing these statement in your code after several iterations using a binary search approach you will be able to locate the line that produces the strange output.

Comment: Hello Leon, I am really stuck. I did what you sayed with the print commands to find out where the problems is, iam sure it is in this part plc.writeMem:: Because when i print the results they are numbers temp_woonkamer = 0.0 and temp1 = 0.0
If I instead of processing the value in to plc.writemem() but also print it youll see there is a clean result, so something on plc.writeMem is going wrong. Do i need to post my S71200 object?:

`pi@raspberrypi:~/scripts $ python Temp_buiten.py`
`@▒▒▒`
`5.3`
`A▒~▒`
`21.062`
`pi@raspberrypi:~/scripts $`

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not an expert in either PLC or RPI and cannot help you further.

Comment: Ok Leon, thanks anyway. I hope someone passed by with some knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0):

Dave it looks like the S71200 python library you are using prints that to the console every time it is called. [source to S71200.py](https://github.com/SimplyAutomationized/raspberrypi/blob/master/S7-1200pi/S71200.py) on line 106
I must have forgotten to take it out.  -SimplyAutomationized

I just submitted a fix if you want to redownload it.  cheers

Comment: Hello Entrabiter, I tested it and it works like charm. My 1000 times thanks for it. I really love your work!